# Проход текста через условие в цикле программы. С++ Winapi

Tags: c++, массивы, winapi

Написал программку небольшую. Которая сохраняет из EditControl текст в файл. Все просто в целом. Но мне надо подставлять определенные значения в текст, которые заданны в массиве самой программы.
В консольном варианте все просто для меня было а тут я потерялся немного.
Есть такое условие, что бы вместо набранных в EditControl цифр подставлялись буквенные значения.
Вместо 1 - X, 2 - Y, 3 - A, 4 - B.
К примеру набрав строку в Control Edit B+3,2,1,DB2. В файл уже был записан вот такой результат B+A,Y,X,DBY. 
В чем собственно я потерялся? Так в том, что я не могу понять куда подставить этот цикл по замене элементов в массиве. Помогите кто сможет. Я уже неделю с этим мучаюсь.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"

using namespace std;

#define ESC_OF "Отказ от выбора или ошибка выполнения функции "

HWND hEdit1;
HWND hEdit2;

CHAR text_1[] = { 0 };
CHAR text_2[] = { 0 };

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );

int CALLBACK WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                      int nCmdShow )
{
    DialogBoxParam( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDD_DIALOG1 ), 0, ( DlgProc ), 0 );
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc( HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    BOOL success;
    static OPENFILENAME ofn;
    static char szFile[MAX_PATH];

    switch( uMsg ) {
        case WM_INITDIALOG: { // Добавление компонентов на форму
            // Инициализация структуры ofn
            ofn.lStructSize = sizeof( OPENFILENAME );
            ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
            ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
            ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof( szFile );
            ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
            ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";
            //Иконка
            HICON hIcon1 = LoadIcon( GetModuleHandle( NULL ),
                                     MAKEINTRESOURCE( IDI_ICON1 ) );
            SendMessage( hwnd, WM_SETICON, 1, ( LPARAM )hIcon1 );
            //Текстовые поля
            hEdit1 = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_EDIT1 );
            hEdit2 = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_EDIT2 );
            SetWindowText( hEdit1, text_1 );
            SetFocus( hEdit1 );
            break;
            return TRUE;
        }

        case WM_COMMAND: // Обработка кнопок и нажатий
            switch( LOWORD( wParam ) ) {
                case IDC_BUTTON1:
                    strcpy_s( szFile, "" );
                    success = GetSaveFileName( &ofn );

                    if( success ) {
                        MessageBox( hwnd, ofn.lpstrFile,
                                    "Файл сохранен под именем:", MB_OK );
                        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile( ofn.lpstrFile,
                                                   GENERIC_WRITE,
                                                   FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                                                   NULL,
                                                   CREATE_ALWAYS,
                                                   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                                                   NULL );
                        const int size = 2048;
                        TCHAR buff[size] = { 0 };
                        hEdit2 = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_EDIT2 );
                        DWORD off = 0;

                        do {
                            GetWindowText( hEdit2, buff, size );
                            WriteFile( hFile, buff, size, &off, NULL );
                        } while( off < 0 );

                        CloseHandle( hFile );
                    }
                    else {
                        MessageBox( hwnd, ESC_OF"GetSaveFileName",
                                    "Отказ от выбора или ошибка", MB_ICONWARNING );
                    }

                    break;

                case IDOK:
                    MessageBox( hwnd, "Была нажата кнопка ОК", "Info",
                                MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION );
                    break;

                case IDCANCEL:
                    EndDialog( hwnd, 0 );
                    return FALSE;
            }

            break;

        case WM_CLOSE:
            EndDialog( hwnd, 0 );
            return FALSE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: `Написал программку небольшую.` - покажите код.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Не разобрался пока как правильно тут оформлять код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обработчике нажатия кнопки **case IDC_BUTTON1:**
есть цикл:

```
do {
    GetWindowText( hEdit2, buff, size );
    WriteFile( hFile, buff, size, &off, NULL );
} while( off < 0 );
```

**GetWindowText()** - берет текст из контрола и складывает его в массив *buff*. 
**WriteFile()** - записывает этот массив *buff* в файл.

Соответственно, нужно между этими двумя вызовами функций подправить содержимое *buff* как Вам надо (т.е. вставить цикл по замене символов).